# Identity mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> **Problem:** Show that the identity mapping is the only ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> **Solution:** Let $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be a ring homomorphism. Then $\varphi(0)=0$ and $\varphi(1) = 1$. For each positive $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\varphi(n) = \varphi(1+1+\cdots+1) = \varphi(1)+\varphi(1)+\cdots+\varphi(1) = n\varphi(1)$. For each negative $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we know that $−n>0$, and $\varphi(n) = −\varphi(−n) = −(−n) = n$. So $\varphi$ is the identity function.
>
> ([Source](http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/%7Emnogin/math151fall08/hw13-sol.pdf))

---

**Question:** Why is it true that $\varphi(n) = −\varphi(−n)$? My reasoning is that $n=1\cdot n=-1\cdot(-n)$ because $1,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring. So I see that $\varphi(n)=\varphi(-1\cdot(-n))=\varphi(-1)\cdot\varphi(-n)$, but can I say that $\varphi(-1)=-1$?

Comment: Negation is a ring operation, thus is preserved by ring homomorphisms.

Answer (score 5):

$\varphi (n)+\varphi(-n)=\varphi(n+(-n))=\varphi(0)=0$, that's why. And this is valid for any ring homomorphism in any ring.